# converting image_raw to image_rect from kinect data

Tags: ros, kinect, openni, bagfile, fovis-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
i downloaded bagefile from `mit stata center data set` for testing fovis package. for kinect data(mono depth). fovis subscribing from this topices:

```
/camera/rgb/image_rect
/camera/depth_registered/image_rect 
/camera/rgb/camera_info
/camera/depth_registered/camera_info
```

but MIT bage file has this packages:

```
/camera/depth/camera_info
/camera/depth/image_raw
/camera/rgb/camera_info
/camera/rgb/image_raw
```

i used this command to play bagfiles: `rosbag play 2012-04-26-06-48-00.bag`.
so, what i do for solve this problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/126341/converting-image_raw-to-image_rect-from-kinect-data/) by [Mahyar](https://answers.ros.org/users/4281/mahyar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2014-02-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i used the http://wiki.ros.org/image_proc package for solving my problem.

---

Originally posted by [Mahyar](https://answers.ros.org/users/4281/mahyar/) with karma: 18 on 2014-05-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0